# Format Excel Pie of Pie Chart with C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, formatting, pie-chart

I'm using C# to create an Excel sheet with a chart on it. I'm using a pie of pie chart because some of the data are very small and won't be visible in a normal pie chart. Everything works fine, but I need some help with formatting. I'll give you some code and hopefully you can help:

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlChart = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChart.Add(350, 30, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("a3", "b6");
chartPage.SetSourceData(range, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlPieOfPie;
```

How can I specify which data I want to have in the secondary chart of the pie of pie chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

```
        myChart.Activate();
        Excel.ChartGroup group = chartPage.ChartGroups(1);
        //put the last 3 values in the second pie
        group.SplitValue = 3;
```